# asp.net combine & compress css, js files

Tags: php, asp.net, css

I have this code in PHP for combining and compressing css and js files.

```
$css = '';
$files = explode(',',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
if( 'css' == $files[0] ){
    $type = 'css';
    $root = 'css/';
}else if( 'javascript' == $files[0] ){
    $type = 'js';
    $root = 'js/';
}
header("Content-type: text/$files[0]");
    ob_start("compress");
    function compress($buffer) {
    $buffer = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*\/!', '', $buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $buffer);
    return $buffer;
    }
if(sizeof($files))
{
  foreach($files as $file)
  {
    $css.= (is_file($root.$file.'.' . $type) ? file_get_contents($root.$file.'.' . $type) : '');
  }
}
echo $css;
```

How can I compress and combine css and js files with asp.net

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Hanselman has a [good post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceAndEaseOfMinifyingYourCSSAndJavaScriptAndOptimizingPNGsForYourBlogOrWebsite.aspx) on doing this in .NET.

The latest version of .NET allows you to do this easily via [built-in support](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/11/27/new-bundling-and-minification-support-asp-net-4-5-series.aspx).

Here's a list of other tools that allow you do this:

- [Combine and minify](http://combineandminify.codeplex.com/)
- [Rejuicer](http://rejuice.me/)
- [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/) - [Instructions](http://tomphilip.me/index.php/cassette-the-javascript-css-minifying-combining-compressing-tool-for-asp-net/)
- [Automatic minify and combine](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33552/Automatically-Minify-Combine-Compress-and-Cache-js)
- [Combres](http://combres.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Good roundup of available tools

Answer (score 1):

I have had an excellent experience with [Combres](http://combres.codeplex.com/).

It's very easy to set up and haven't had any major issues with it in the last 2 years.